# PHP, MySQL: can't explain this undefined index error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm getting an undefined index error with this code:

```
// Select all bookings
$sql = "SELECT * FROM booking";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<p>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // echo $row['custName'] . " - " . $row['roomNb'] . " - " . $row['date'];
    echo $row['custName'];
}
```

Error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: custName in C:\xampp\htdocs\alxbook\index.php on line 40
```

I'm selecting all columns from my table. I have no problem with $row['roomNb'] and $row['date'] but for some reason $row['custName'] is giving me problems. The spelling of custName is correct.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Column does not exists in table, it seems. Show your table's structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a piece of debug code into your script to proove that the name is correct:-

```
// Select all bookings
$sql = "SELECT * FROM booking";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<p>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    print_r( $row );  // debug code

    // echo $row['custName'] . " - " . $row['roomNb'] . " - " . $row['date'];
    echo $row['custName'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It appears the column name contained a space at the beginning. Very confusing as the space char does not appear in phpmyadmin! (that is probably a bug no?) So it was a typo from when I created the tables.
But by using your debug code the space char does appear.

Thank you

Comment: @user2018084 I would remove the space from the column name rather than put something into php to remove it.